# How to change the operator for a views contextual filter?

Tags: views

I am using the views module to present data as a table (block) from a mysql database. The table is filtered based on the raw value from the pages URL path. View only allows for the contextual filter to be an exact match to the field value.

How can I change this operator to "LIKE"?

Currently I added this custom views query which should alter the views query

```
<?php

/**
 * Implements hook_views_query_alter
 *
 * Finds the correct view, and calls a relevant callback
 */
function customviewsquery_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
switch($view->name) {
case 'alkon_valikoima_ryp_le':
  _customviewsquery_my_view_name_views_query_alter($view, $query);
  break;
}
}

/**
* Callback to fix the Views 3 query object before execution
*/
function _customviewsquery_my_view_name_views_query_alter(&$view, &$query) {
// Loop through the conditional parts of the query, and
// * Change = to LIKE
// * Add SQL wildcard characters to both sides of the value
foreach($query->where as $key => $val) {
$field = $val['conditions'][0]['field'];
$operator = $val['conditions'][0]['operator'];
$value = $val['conditions'][0]['value'];

if($field == 'alko_tb.grape_alko' && $operator == '=') {
  $query->where[$key]['conditions'][0]['operator'] = 'LIKE';
  $query->where[$key]['conditions'][0]['value'] = '%' . $value . '%';
}

}
}
```

The machine name for my view is "alkon_valikoima_ryp_le" and the field is the database "alko_tb" under the "grape_alko" column.

What could be wrong with this approach?

Comment: I guess it's just a typo, but `alko_tb` is a table, not a database. As for what can go wrong, did you try it?

Comment: I'd assume this is the original source: http://n00bsys0p.co.uk/blog/2012/08/21/drupal-views-3-contextual-filter, You should give more information, what is wrong? 1. your code is not called or 2. it does not behave the way you want it to? to see if your code is called use a php debugger or simply install devel module and use the function `dpm()`